# CSAPP confuse with pushtest result Practice Problem 4.7

Tags: y86

`Y86` is similar to `x86-64`. Why function pushtest always returns zero?

As I know on `x86-64` Push decrements the ESP register first than writes.
Pop read first than increments the ESP register.

```
    .text
.globl pushtest
pushtest:
    movq    %rsp, %rax
    pushq   %rsp
    popq    %rdx
    subq    %rdx, %rax
    ret
```

Comment: I think [This web side](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024284/11768871) may be answer this question. May be "pushq   %rsp" is a special case. I am not sure this is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

First. You should not modify `%rsp` (which is Stack Pointer register) manually, don't do `movq    %rsp, ...`. The `%rsp` is (and must only be) managed by `push`, `pop`, `call`, `ret`. Check also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023208/do-i-understand-the-stack-properly-in-this-y86-assembly-code).

Then it's always `%rdx`==0 at the end, because:

```
movq    %rsp, %rax  ; %rsp==%rax
pushq   %rsp        ; top of the stack := %rsp == %rax
popq    %rdx        ; %rdx := top of the stack == %rax
subq    %rdx, %rax  ; %rdx := %rdx - %rax , i.e. %rdx := %rax - %rax == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I reference [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39339435/11768871) the "pushq" can be replaced by "subq and movq", "popq" can be replace d by "movq and addq".

But "PUSH ESP" and "POP ESP" are the special case. Reference [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49022979/does-pushl-esp-update-esp-before-or-after-storing/49024284#49024284).
But result not "0"

**pushq   %rsp** ;pushes the value of the ESP register as it existed before the instruction was executed.

**popq    %rsp** ;increments the stack pointer (ESP) before data at the old top of stack is written into the destination.

**pushq   %rdx** ;Decrements the stack pointer and then stores the source operand on the top of the stack.

**popq    %rdx** ;Loads the value from the top of the stack to the location specified with the destination operand (or explicit opcode) and then increments the stack pointer.

```
rax =
rdx =

0x28 |  0x12  |
0x30 |  0x34  | <--- rsp
0x38 |  0x56  |
0x40 |  0x78  |
0x48 |  0x9A  |


movq    %rsp, %rax
rax = 0x30
rdx =

0x28 |  0x12  |
0x30 |  0x34  | <--- rsp
0x38 |  0x56  |
0x40 |  0x78  |
0x48 |  0x9A  |


pushq   %rsp ;store, using rsp as the address, then subtract 8 from rsp
rax = 0x30
rdx =

0x28 |  0x12  | <--- rsp
0x30 |  0x30  |
0x38 |  0x56  |
0x40 |  0x78  |
0x48 |  0x9A  |


popq    %rdx ;load, using rsp as the address, then add 8 to the rsp
rax = 0x30
rdx = 0x30

0x28 |  0x12  | <--- rsp
0x30 |  0x30  |
0x38 |  0x56  |
0x40 |  0x78  |
0x48 |  0x9A  |

subq    %rdx, %rax    ;Return 0
rax = 0x00
rdx = 0x30

0x28 |  0x12  |
0x30 |  0x30  | <--- rsp
0x38 |  0x56  |
0x40 |  0x78  |
0x48 |  0x9A  |
```